# Does the rsync "-a" option exclude the "-A" and "-X" option?

Tags: rsync, acl, archive, xattr

Rsync describes the `-a` or `--archive mode` as being equivalent to the options.`-rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)`.

The `-A` and `-X` options are ambiguous and iit is not clear whether they are included or excluded.

`-A` stands for `--acls` and `-X` stands for `--xattrs` and I wonder whether they are excluded because they are features added on top the Unix file system, although you would expect an archive backup to include them.

Is there something about extended attributes and access control lists that make it unwise to include them in an archive backup?

Are they stored separately from the files that use them, in a way that makes them inapplicable to an archived backup?

Comment: Are you asking _if_ they're excluded, or _why_?

Comment: It's pretty clear that `-H`, `-A`, and `-X` are excluded from the meta option `-a` from the part of the manual that you quoted. Your question is therefore better rephrased as being about _why_ these are excluded.  The question itself is currently unclear.

Comment: "_The -A and -X options are ambiguous_" not from where I sit. Please update your question to explain what you want to know about them.

Comment: "_iit is not clear whether they are included or excluded_" it's absolutely clear. Even the section of the man page you quoted states that they are excluded

Comment: This is more than one question. One question is if `-a` disables explicitely given `-A -X` (when I understand you correctly) and another one is if you should backup acls and extended attributes, which should probably be an own question.

Comment: If the question is [i]why[/i]?, I have a hypothesis: -A, -X, -U, -N, and -H are not included in --archive because they may fail on some OS's or file systems.  F.ex., -N fails fails for me on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The -A and -X options are ambiguous and iit is not clear whether they are included or excluded.

It should be relatively simple to test how the options behave.

Create a test file with an ACL, copy it with the various options and combinations of them, and see if the copied file has the ACL. (Remove the target file after each copy.)

I'll spare you the full output, but via testing, I see that neither `rsync`, or `rsync -a` copies the ACL; but all of `rsync -A`, `rsync -a -A` and `rsync -A -a` do copy it.

So indeed `-A` is not included in `-a`, but `-a` also doesn't exclude `-A` in the sense of making it not work if explicitly given. `-X` works similar.

FWIW, this matches how I would have read the man page, that `-a` is simply the same as `-rlptgoD` (with a note on how `-AX` are not included).

> I wonder whether they are excluded because they are features added on top the Unix file system

As for the why `-a` doesn't include `-AX`, I suppose we'd need to ask the developers. It's possible that they thought the features in question aren't common enough to warrant that, or that most users would not be aware of how they work, or that trying to read and store ACLs and/or xattrs would lead to errors or other issues in some systems.

> Is there something about extended attributes and access control lists that make it unwise to include them in an archive backup?

That's harder to say, and probably depends on your use-case and what exactly you have there in the xattrs (and ACLs).